Linear coupled recursive relations and finding the limit of the ratio
Let $a_0,b_0$ be any two positive integers. Define $a_n,b_n$ using the relations:
$$a_n=a_{n-1}+2b_{n-1}, b_n=a_{n-1}+b_{n-1} \forall n \in N$$
Find: $$\lim_{n \to ∞} \dfrac{a_n}{b_n}$$
My attempt:
I've never really worked with coupled recursive relations before but here's what I tried.
Let $r_n=a_n/b_n$. Then, $\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}=r_{n-1}+2$ and $\dfrac{b_n}{b_{n-1}}=r_{n-1}+1$ So, if I can somehow determine the ratios of either $a_n/a_{n-1}$ or $b_n/b_{n-1}$ as $n$ tends to $∞$, I shall be done. However, I'm unable to extract any explicit expression for $a_n$ or $b_n$ from the given relations using the elementary methods I know; I briefly also considered constructing some sort of characteristic equation $f_n(x,y)$ whose roots are these sequences but that doesn't yield any results either.
How should I approach this problem?

The simplest (in terms of least amount of thinking!) approach might be to just solve the system for $a_n$ and $b_n$ first, then look at their ratio. (To do that you need to manipulate the recurrence relations to get a single relation for either $a_n$ or $b_n$.)

Ah, I got it; $b_n=2b_{n-1}+b_{n-2}$

Yep! Another idea, by the way, is to just divide one of your recurrence relations by the other. Then you find $r_n=\frac{r_{n-1}+2}{r_{n-1}+1}$ and you can work from there. It's easy to find the limit that way, but it's a slightly harder relation to work with (remember you'd have to prove convergence)

The given system can be written as $$ \begin{pmatrix}
a \\ b
\end{pmatrix}_{n+1}=\underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 \\ 1&1
\end{pmatrix}}_{=A} \begin{pmatrix}
a \\ b
\end{pmatrix}_n.$$
We can see that the equilibrium (or the fixed point) of the system is $(a,b)=(0,0)$. And the eigenvalues of the difference system $A$ are $\lambda_{1}=1-\sqrt{2}$ and $\lambda_{2}=1+\sqrt{2}$, so $|\lambda_1|<1$ and $|\lambda_2|>1$. This means that our fixed point is a saddle point (one stable and one unstable manifold). Unless the initial conditions are on the stable manifold (or since the system is linear, we can refer to that as the stable direction), the solution will converge on the unstable manifold/direction. And the unstable direction is equivalent to the eigenvector $\boldsymbol{v}$ corresponding to $\lambda_{2}=1+\sqrt{2}$, and that is
$$ \boldsymbol{v}=\begin{pmatrix}
\sqrt{2} \\ 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$ Therefore, we can see that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{a_n}{b_n}=\sqrt{2}$. For the initial conditions that are in the stable direction, the same approach can be used.
